# Problem getting list of related purchase order lines in sales order line

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

In my domain several purchase order lines can be assigned to one sales order line.
When the purchase order is created it is saved in the database with a new natural Primary Key (DocEntry, LineNum) and gets. The sales order's natural primary keys are stored in the pair (BaseEntry, BaseLine).

I can't get DirectDeliveryPurchaseOrderLines loaded and i am trying for days.

```cs
    ------------------     --------------------------
    |OrderDocumentLine|    |PurchaseOrderDocumentLine|
    ------------------     --------------------------|
    |DocEntry(PK)     |--> |BaseEntry                |
    |LineNum(PK)      |--> |BaseLine                 |
    ------------------|    |DocEntry (PK)            |
                           |LineNum (PK)             |
                           |--------------------------|

namespace Domain.Documents
{
    public class OrderDocumentLine:DocumentLineBase
    {
        public OrderDocumentLine()
        {

        }

        public virtual int DocEntry { get; set; }

        public virtual int LineNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual ISet<PurchaseOrderDocumentLine> DirectDeliveryPurchaseOrderLines { get; set; } = new HashSet<PurchaseOrderDocumentLine> ();
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Domain"
                   namespace="Domain.Documents">
    <class name="OrderDocumentLine" table="rdr1">
        <synchronize table="por1"/>
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="DocEntry"/>
            <key-property name="LineNumber" column="LineNum"/>
        </composite-id>
        <set name="DirectDeliveryPurchaseOrderLines" table="por1" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="BaseEntry"/>
                <column name="BaseLine"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="PurchaseOrderDocumentLine"/>

        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Domain"
                   namespace="Domain.Documents">

    <class name="PurchaseOrderDocumentLine" table="por1">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="DocEntry"/>
            <key-property name="LineNumber" column="LineNum"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="BaseLineNumber" column="BaseLine"/>
        <property name="BaseDocEntry" column="BaseEntry"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
public class PurchaseOrder : Entity // Entity is just for Id
{
    public virtual IList<PurchaseOrderLine> OrderLines { get; protected set; } = new List<PurchaseOrderLine>();

    public virtual PurchaseOrderLine AddLine()
    {
        var line = new PurchaseOrderLine { PurchaseOrder = this, Line = OrderLines.Count + 1 };
        OrderLines.Add(line);
        return line;
    }
}

public class Order : Entity
{
    public virtual IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; protected set; } = new List<OrderLine>();
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual int Line { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<PurchaseOrderLine> PurchaseOrderLines { get; protected set; } = new HashSet<PurchaseOrderLine>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as OrderLine;
        return other != null && other.Order == Order && other.Line == Line;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Line;
}


public class PurchaseOrderLine
{
    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual int Line { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as PurchaseOrderLine;
        return other != null && other.PurchaseOrder == PurchaseOrder && other.Line == Line;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Line;
}
```

mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="OrderLine" table="`OrderLine`">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Order" column="DocEntry" />
      <key-property name="Line" column="LineNum" />
    </composite-id>
    <set name="PurchaseOrderLines" table="por1">
      <key>
        <column name="DocEntry" />
        <column name="LineNum" />
      </key>
      <many-to-many class="PurchaseOrderLine">
        <column name="BaseEntry" />
        <column name="BaseLine" />
      </many-to-many>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NHibernateTest.S16.PurchaseOrderLine, NHibernateTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`PurchaseOrderLine`">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="PurchaseOrder" column="BaseEntry" />
      <key-property name="Line" column="BaseLine" />
    </composite-id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Testcode

```
var purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
session.Save(purchaseOrder);
var line1 = purchaseOrder.AddLine();
var line2 = purchaseOrder.AddLine();
session.Save(line1);
session.Save(line2);

var order = new Order();
session.Save(order);
order.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine { Order = order, Line = 1, PurchaseOrderLines = { line1, line2 } });
session.Flush();
session.Clear();
var line = session.Query<OrderLine>().First();
var pLineCount = line.PurchaseOrderLines.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for me the solution is not clear. How did you define the Order/PurchaseOrder or is this not relevant?
How can you create new purchase order lines  if the composite key is pair (BaseEntry, BaseLine) instead of (DocEntry, DocLine)?

Comment: I thought they were not relevant. As i understand it, there are already purchaseorderlines from purchases and you want to connect them to the orderlines, right?

Comment: Thanks for caring! That is right. But there must also be the possibility to update purchase orders. And they are not related to sales orders all the time.

Comment: Moreover i get a "Foreign key (FK_1563977C:por1 [BaseEntry, BaseLine])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (por1 [DocEntry, LineNum, BaseEntry, BaseLine])" error message

Comment: the example has 2 seperate aggregated roots with lines. Connecting them is optional. This error implies that you have a mapping for por1 while in the example the table por1 is only present as the many-to-many mapping.